# How to add external JavaScript and jQuery files to Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5, swiper.js, nuxt3

I added the CSS files correctly in Nuxt 3 and nuxt.config.ts and it works correctly.

Now in what folder should I add these script files? What's the best possible solution for this problem.

Comment: Is there any reasons why you wanted to use jquery on Nuxt3? Most jquery features are achievable using Nuxt. But, if you really needed it, yes you can. Same for plain javascript

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your CSS or JS files inside `/public` dir and on any component you can use `useHead()` composable.

```js
useHead({
  link: [
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    href: '/your_css_file_name.css'
  ]
})
```